# Merging curved arrows in chemfig (or tikz?)

Tags: diagrams, tikz-arrows, arrows, chemfig, flow-charts

I'm fairly new to Latex and I've been using chemfig to draw a couple of diagrams so far, but for this one I'm trying to do I've not found a way. I haven't used tikz before, but it seems to me that it would be the better option here. Nevertheless I can't find any example of what I'm looking for anywhere so I thought I would just ask.

Basically what I want to do is this:

[image]

But I haven't been able to come even close and don't have a single line of code to show for it.
Can anyone help?

EDIT:
I've very clumsily thrown together this following code, which is kind of what I wanted, but I'm hoping there's a neater way to do it. Also I would very much like the arrows to touch/merge in some way.

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\node (a) at (0,0) {A};
\node (b) at (2,0) {B};
\draw[-latex,bend right]  (a) edge (b);
\end{tikzpicture}\\
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node (c) at (0,0) {C};
\node (d) at (2,0) {D};
\draw[-latex,bend left]  (c) edge (d);
\draw[-latex,bend left]  (d) edge (c);
\end{tikzpicture}\\
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node (e) at (0,0) {E};
\node (f) at (2,0) {F};
\draw[-latex,bend right]  (f) edge (e);
\draw[-latex,bend right]  (e) edge (f);
\end{tikzpicture}\\
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node (g) at (0,0) {G};
\node (h) at (2,0) {H};
\draw[-latex,bend left]  (g) edge (h);
\end{tikzpicture}


\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Hi and welcome to TeX.SX. To get a faster and better-suited answer to your question, it would be best if you gave us something to work with. Show us what you got so far. A minimal working example starting with `/documentclass{` and ending with `\end{document}` would let us run things on our side and find the solution you see.

Comment: Edited the post to include an example!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You only need to draw the `\node`s (A,B,C,...) and the `arc`s. To draw an `arc` you need to write

```
\draw (1,2) arc (0:90:3);
```

which means that you are drawing an `arc` starting at point `(1,2)` with inital angle `0`, ending angle `90` and radius `3`.

Something like this:

```
\documentclass[border=2mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{babel} % just in case
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[y={(0,-1cm)}, shorten >= 2mm, shorten <= 2mm,]
  \def\s{1} % separation between nodes
  \node (A) at ( 0,   0) {$A$};
  \node (B) at (\s,   0) {$B$};
  \node (C) at ( 0,  \s) {$C$};
  \node (D) at (\s,  \s) {$D$};
  \node (E) at ( 0,2*\s) {$E$};
  \node (F) at (\s,2*\s) {$F$};
  \node (G) at ( 0,3*\s) {$G$};
  \node (H) at (\s,3*\s) {$H$};
  \draw[->] (A) arc (180:  0:0.5*\s);
  \draw[->] (C) arc (180:360:0.5*\s);
  \draw[->] (D) arc (  0:180:0.5*\s);
  \draw[->] (E) arc (180:  0:0.5*\s);
  \draw[->] (F) arc (360:180:0.5*\s);
  \draw[->] (H) arc (360:180:0.5*\s);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

will draw:

[image]

Comment: This is great, thank you so much! I have two follow-up questions, I'm not sure if this is the place to pose them but here they are:
(1) How can I control the distance between the nodes and arcs (vertically in this case)? 
(2) And what if I wanted to label the pairs of arrows on the right hand side of this flowchart? Is there a way to do this so the label is centered on the arrow-pair?

Comment: @Lilo, the vertical and horizontal distance can be modified with the parameter `\s`. You can define two variables for horizontal and vertical distance, but in this case you need to change the center of the arcs if you still want the arrows touching one another. For the second question, you need to add a `\node` in the desired position. Here `1.5*\s` gives the middle point height between D and F, for example.

Comment: Perfect, thank you!